When is Normal force 0?
Let's say 2 bodies are in contact and are placed on a frictionless surface, both of them being at rest, so there isn't any normal contact force acting between the 2 bodies. So my question is even though the 2 bodies are in contact here but the normal force between them is still 0, but according to the definition normal force should act between bodies in contact?? So when does the normal force between 2 bodies in contact act and when does it not??

What's the difference between "no normal force" and "normal force of 0"?

Could you cite the definition of Normal Force that you are using?  I think that is the cause of your misconception.  In your post, you mention "...but according to the definition normal force should act between bodies in contact??"  Contact between two bodies is a necessary condition for the Normal force, but it is not sufficient by itself.  Just because two bodies are in contact does not mean that there is a Normal force between them.  One of the bodies must be supporting the other against against a force.

If these bodies are not massless there is a normal force between them calculated from a theory of gravitation.

All objects are at least slightly compressible, no matter how rigid they are. Therefore, they act "spring-like" when pushed on. Thus, when two objects are placed just in contact with each other, but they aren't pushing into each other to make them compress, then there's no outward elastic force because the "springs" aren't compressed. However, if the two objects are pressed together so that each slightly deforms inward, then they exert an elastic force outward on the other object.  This force (or at least the component of this force that is perpendicular to the surfaces in contact) is known as the normal force.
That is, think of the normal force between two objects as a force arising from the fact that the objects are actually slightly compressible, and so they act as springs.

Note that most solids have insane spring constants!  This means treating them as rigid with this "magic normal force" that happens to scale with the forces used to push them together works; neglecting the tiny amount of deformation doesn't cause any problems with the solution.

I am assuming you are talking about two objects at rest on a flat surface as illustrated below
The two arrows signify the normal force that exist between each block and the flat surface they rest on due to the effects of gravity.
You have to remember the basic force equation is force = mass x acceleration and normal force is strictly defined as the force perpendicular to the surface at the point of contact (more appropriately, perpendicular to the tangent surface at the point of contact)

So if there is truly no motion difference, or other non-equilibrium condition to generate an acceleration difference between the blocks themselves then there is no normal force between the blocks, however there is a normal vector defined of magnitude zero between the blocks.
Normal force between blocks is represented by two opposing zero magnitude normal vectors


"You have to remember the basic force equation is force = mass x acceleration."  That's not entirely correct. NET force = mass x acceleration.

So, if a body is just placed on a frictionless horizontal surface, it will exert a normal force on the surface and the surface will exert a normal force on the body, if gravity or any other external pressing force is present.
Cause of norma force:
Normal force arise due to pressing against two bodies, if there is no pressing then normal force will not arise.
So, if a normal force will act or not depends on the presence or absence of pressing force.

Normal force is a reaction to a good old push acting on some body. A simple contact doesn't suffice for a normal force to generate. Someone must push on someone else so that the someone else can push back. That's what Normal force (reaction) is. Two bodies resting on any surface, in contact, wouldn't necessarily have some normal force between them unless one of them applies a force on the other. Remember, normal force is a reaction to another force and not a free-exsiting force in itself.
